# Magento 1.9 Customer Group Display Price Without Tax

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, customer-group

I have created a Tax Free Customer Group, so when a customer logged in, the price should be displayed without tax. And this is working find on a clean Magento installation.

When I implement this on my live site, all prices are displayed with tax. It simply ignored my Tax Free Customer Group.

I have the following code to display price, which is the same code as in a clean Magento installation.

```
$this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue())
```

Any reason why this code doesn't take customer group in consideration?

PS: I've also checked the admin, which is the same setup as in a clean Magento installation, where the tax free customer group worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed it.

It's the [**Enable Cross Border Trade**](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-cross-border-price.html) calculation setting under System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax, that needs to be turned off.

Comment: mark it as the answer